# [__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI elements]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2836c2820

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

Well, I should remember you I am still a beginner in iOS development with objective c. And maybe because of this, the solution is simple but I can´t see it. I have a json who is armed in the following way :

```
{
   "origin_addresses": [
      "Test"
   ],
   "rows": [
      {
         "elements": [
            {
               "distance": {
                  "text": "0.3 km",
                  "value": 339
               },
               "duration": {
                  "text": "1 min",
                  "value": 82
               },
               "status": "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status": "OK"
}
```

The app can consume the service without problems. My goal is to reach the distance attribute. Which I do as follows. I use a foreach to get through the array **rows** and then another foreach to get through the array **elements**.

```
for (BPCGARows *item in googleAddress.rows) {
            NSLog(@"rows : %@", item);
            for (BPCGAElements *element in item.elements) {

            }
        }
```

When I'm debugging the app, my first for each works without problems, but when I access the second foreach the **(BPCGAElements * element in item.elements)** the app crashes. Finally I can't print the item.elements in a log either. The error message is as follows:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI
>   elements]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281c75da0'

header BPCGADistance :

```
@interface BPCGADistance : MBOInspectableModel

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSNumber *value;

@end
```

main BPCGADistance:

```
@interface BPCGADistance()

@property (nonatomic, strong, setter=text:) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, strong, setter=value:) NSNumber *value;

@end
```

---

header BPCGAElements :

```
@interface BPCGADistance : MBOInspectableModel

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSNumber *value;

@end
```

main BPCGAElements:

```
@interface BPCGADistance()

@property (nonatomic, strong, setter=text:) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, strong, setter=value:) NSNumber *value;

@end
```

---

This is my NSLog(@"rows : %@", item),
I emphasize that by using the item.elements to print the crashea app on the console. ;

[image]

Comment: `BPCGARows *item` is a `NSDictionary`, not a `BPCGARows`. How did you converted the JSON into your custom objects (`BPCGARows`, `BPCGAElements`)?

Comment: I just updated my answer by adding the BPCGARows and BPCGAElements models. @Larme

Comment: But as I mentioned my model is well generated since I can print it on the console the response of the service. @Larme

Comment: What's the output of `NSLog(@"rows : %@", item);`? What you gave? Because that's JSON, not a `BPCGARows`. Where did you init the JSON response into your custom objects?

Comment: @Larme I just updated my question by adding the print in console

Comment: Looks like a NSDictionary/NSArray, not a `BPCGARows` You get JSON, right? Where did you do your API call?

Comment: I really remind you that there are no problems with the service, the error is there, and add my models and functionality. But I don't understand why he gives that message in the second for each with the item.element @Larme

Comment: Having a model doesn’t mean you parse the JSOn correctly. Right now, I think you just castes and never called [[BPCGARow alloc] init] anywhere.

Comment: [[BPCGARow alloc] init] ? Well no, then what would be the solution? so how do i access the json distance attribute. @Larme

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208430/discussion-between-larme-and-dbenitobaldeon).